# How do 3D models physics mechanics work (how is it setup to behave a certain way)

Tags: 3d, game-physics, game-development

trying to make a program that uses 3D models and some physics integration, but I dont understand how a 3D model is made to have certain specific properties related to physics, such as collision.

A complex example, let’s say i have a model of a 3D person. How can I make the 3D model have physics properties such as collision for a point somewhere on the body? e.g: on a hand, the point between the index finger and middle finger (between the two knuckles), how would the model have physics properties like collision for this specific spot on the 3d person models hand setup?

As simpler example, a 3D basketball. How does the model/program know which way to “react” when for example bouncing the ball and then some x,y point on the basketball hits the ground, how does it know how to react to hitting that one point on the ground (e.g ball spins left when bouncing back up as a result, ball spins rights when bouncing back up as a result, ball bounces up spinning diagonally, etc…

Comment: You need to clarify what you are actually looking for: The question is tagged unreal-engine5, but as far as I know, UE5 has a integrated physics engine that you just need to configure. If you are looking for the theory behind a physics engine, that's too broad for SO. There are whole books written just about collision detection, and that's just the first step to handling correct collision responses.

Comment: I am trying to make a 3d mini game on the web. Not sure if it's different from Unreal, but this question really came up when I was browsing for 3d models I can buy, for example on Sketchfab. I dont know how these 3d models are setup to have physics properties, like what I described in OP. Same for building my own 3d models with a library such as three.js or babylon

Comment: Usually, 3D models don't come with physics properties attached. They depend to much on the physics engine being used and of the coupeling between the physics subsystem and the rendering subsystem. Most rigid body physics engines aren't really calculating the physics on the actual mesh, but on a simplified collision body (a sphere, box, capsule). I highly recommend picking a physics engine of your choice, start with a simple testcase like a bouncing ball, then continue from there when you got an impression of what you need.

Comment: Basically that means if I want a 3d model of a person to also have physics property on some specific part on the body, such as between two fingers, the 3d engine/physics engine software that made it needs to have that feature/suipport